# Android Screen Timeout

Tags: java, android, android-1.5-cupcake

I know its possible to use a  wakelock to hold the screen, cpu, ect on but how can I programmatically change the "**Screen Timeout**" setting on an Android phone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) provider offers a [SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT) setting that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @CommonsWare how can i set the screen off timeout to never?

Comment: I think this only works when lock screen is enabled. How to achieve it if lock screen is disabled?

Answer (score 27):

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity 
{
    private static final int DELAY = 3000;
    int defTimeOut = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Be sure to call the super class.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // See assets/res/any/layout/hello_world.xml for this
        // view layout definition, which is being set here as
        // the content of our screen.
        setContentView(R.layout.hello_world);
        defTimeOut = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), 
                         Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, DELAY);
        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, DELAY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, defTimeOut);
    }
}
```

And also dont forget to add this permission in manifest:

```
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
```

Answer (score 14):

Above is correct:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, DELAY);
```

But also include permission in manifest:

```
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code-sheet, you can do more.

```
long stand = Settings.System.getLong(
                        mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT,
                        -1);
                long sec = stand / 1000;
                String time = null;
                                    if(stand<0) {
                                         //close.
                                    }
                else if( sec >= 60) {//to minute
                    time = String.format(mContext.getString(R.string.minutes), (sec / 60) + "");
                } else {
                    time = String.format( mContext.getString(R.string.seconds),sec + "");
                }
```