# Dim screen upon idle time. Wake up upon screen input

Tags: android, android-studio

So I am fairly new to the world of coding and I am doodling with a little private learning project.
I have made a simple web browser based on WebView for a embedded android 7.1 ELOtouch device.

I have found plenty of articles online on how to turn the screen on/off etc but never really managed to make it work.

What I am trying to do is that the screen dims down to the lowest level after xx amount of time, let’s say 5min. And only dims back up to a defined level upon user touch/screen input.

The unit is always on and don’t have any form for advanced screen adjustments in settings, so as I see it, it has to be done programmatically.

Thankful for and advice or guidance.

Attached one of my sources:

[How to change screen timeout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748861/how-to-change-screen-timeout-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change screen brightness by user touch, you could do like this:

In AndroidManifest.xml file, add this line:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

And in some place of activity class file:

```
    Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 80);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness =0.8f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    startActivity(new Intent(this,DummyActivity.class));
```

Note: when setting up brightness,the modification doesn't take effect immediately, to solve this problem,just start another blank dummy activity and finish it in `Oncreate`()

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    finish();
  }
```

Don' forget to include DummyActivity in AndroidManifest.xml.

**Edited:**

To dim screen after some time, the basic logic is same, and maybe you should create a Timer(TimerTask).
Hope this is helpful!