# Changing iOS Screen Lock Timeout

Tags: ios

Is it possible to programmatically change the screen lock timeout period for an `iPhone`?

Whilst I'm not new to programming in general I am new to `iOS/Xcode` programming so I've checked out 'Developer Help', googled & searched SO but not found any clues as to where to go further.

As far as the app goes, it is for my personal use, not for publishing via `App Store`.

The general idea is that rather than manually going into Settings/Display & Brightness/Auto-Lock to change the timeout from the normal 30 seconds to 2 minutes I will have a simple app which will toggle between the two.

I do not want to jailbreak my phone so that is not an option.

Comment: Your issue sound similar to this one, except this is for IOS, and the following link for Android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748861/how-to-change-screen-timeout-programmatically

Comment: while is your app active:: Can you use idleTimerDisabled property?

Comment: I can't use the idleTimerDisplayed property because I want the idle timer to apply when other apps are open. My app would only be used to change the idle time. I manually change the idle timeout on my phone almost every day because it is normally on 30 seconds for security and power saving but frequently want it to be longer if I am showing someone else something on the phone or reading something on the phone whilst my hands are otherwise engaged.