# Automatically lock time

Tags: android

i've already asked this question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741764/time-lock-after-sleep) before but i've been misunderstood.
So now i try to be more explicit.

In Android system settings there's an option under Security called "Automatically lock". By default it's set to 5 second. 
I need to programmatically get that value.

Before you marked my question as duplicated of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114270/android-screen-timeout) question but it isn't the same.

To be more clear i put here 2 screenshot:

This is what i need ("Automatically lock"):

[image: What i need "Automatically lock"]

This is what

```
    Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, DELAY);
```

returns. ("Sleep")

[image: What you think i need]

I hope this is more clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Settings.Secure.getLong(getContentResolver(), "lock_screen_lock_after_timeout", 5000);
```

Comment: I get this error:"LOCK_SCREEN_LOCK_AFTER_TIMEOUT cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Answer (score 2):

Thx to srzdev advice i've found out a solution!

```
    int time = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), "lock_screen_lock_after_timeout", 5000);
```

I'm not sure if this work on all android version, i've tested it on 4.2 and 4.3 and it works!

Answer (score -1):

```
 private static final int DELAY = 3000;
    int defTimeOut = 0;    

defTimeOut = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), 
                             Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, DELAY);

            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, DELAY);
```