# Set the delay of the screen saver on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible to change the delay before launching the screen saver on Android ?

Currently I have two methods to enable or disable the KEEP_SCREEN_ON but I can not find anything to handle the sleep time :

```
private fun keepScreenOn() = window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
private fun removeScreenOn() = window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [Android Screen Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114270/android-screen-timeout)

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, DELAY);
```

Add the following permission to your manifest:

```
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
```